# Variable and Value Types

Tags: php

I have a simple question about variable type in php. I have two values in my array:

```
$row['DS'] // type :float (with one decimal like 12.2)
$row['TC'] // type :float (with one decimal like 24.2)
```

What I'm actually try to do in the make the calculation below:

```
$row['TC'] / $row['DS'] // $row['DS'] need to be as integer (without point,like 12)
```

and the result should be with two decimal like (2.32). I tried to do it in that way

```
$DSF = number_format($row['DS'],0);
$ConF = $row['TC'] / $DSF ;
echo number_format($conF,2);
```

but it returns the wrong result. for example :

```
$row['DS'] = 59,009.3 ---> after change the format is change to 59,009
$row['TC'] = 190.0
$ConF = 190.0  /  59,009
```

it should be 000.223 (something around this number ) and i expect to get 0 (after i change the format  using  `number_format($conF,2)` but instead of this the program return  me the number 3.22
What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

The function `number_format()` is used to format numbers to a comma style representation, not to actually round numbers to what you want.

The function you are looking for is [round](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.round.php) which returns a float to a specified number of decimal places.

For example:

```
$yourVar=round($row['TC']/$row['DS'],2);
```

This means that `$yourVar` will be the value of the division rounded to two decimal places.

You should use the `number_format()` function only to display human-friendly numbers at the end.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `type casting` to convert `$row['DS']` to `integer` right in your calculations, for e.g.:

`$row['TC'] / (int)$row['DS']`

or

`$row['TC'] / intval($row['DS'])`